# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 21

Tags: php, opencart

Здраствуйте! У меня появидась проблема, как её устранить?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 21

index.php

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '3.0.2.0');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(__DIR__ . 'startup.php');

start('catalog');
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас в строчке где `require_once` две открывающиеся скобки и одна закрывающая! Поэтому он пугается на символ ';' о чем сообщает данная ошибка